# Problems with Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell XPS 13

Tags: 14.04, drivers, reinstall, reinstalling

I bought me a Dell XPS 13 9343-4228. It came with Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled.
Because I accidentally deleted the X11 folder my system didn't work any more and I did an 'reset' which I found in the Boot loader.

Now I have very big problems with my system: it freezes randomly, when I start it sometimes nothing shows up expect the background and every time there is a little system problem window around.

Can you guys give me any advice? And when you recommend me reinstalling: Do I need any drivers or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Ubuntu 15.04 as it includes a lot of bug fixes.

I have written a [complete step-by-step guide](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide-update/)  on how to install Ubuntu 15.04
and get everything to working properly on the Dell XPS 13 9343 notebook.

**This is what you have to do:**

1. Install Ubuntu 15.04
2. Connect your computer with a USB Wifi/Ethernet adapter and run (to make Wifi work):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```

After that your XPS 13 should work properly (some additional fixes and tweaks may be needed, refer to my guide).